# How to fetch all connected subgraphs using cypher OR TraversalDescription API given a start node type and allowed relationship types

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I want to fetch all the connected subgraphs in my graph which are connected by either of the 2 relationships Rel1 and Rel2. I have a start node type (not the exact node).

Currently I have this following basic query which gives me all paths from n1 to n2 of 2 to 10 hops.

`CYPHER 2.3 MATCH p = (n1:H)-[r:Rel1|Rel2*2..10]-(n2:H) WITH nodes(p) as result return result`

But instead I need connected subgraphs that connect these paths. Any advice or starting point would be helpful.

Other thing i tried was the TraversalDescription java API to do a depth first search but that doesn't take the start node type but a specific start node ?

Attached an example of my graph and what subgraphs i expect from the query.
[image]

Comment: Please, post a sample data set and the expected result.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I attached how my sample graph looks like and the expected answer.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

There are several APOC procedures for [expanding subgraphs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths).

`apoc.path.subgraphNodes` seems to be the most directly relevant to your use case. There are examples of its use [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_to_nodes_in_a_subgraph).

Here is a somewhat simplified example that also uses `apoc.periodic.commit` (which repeatedly executes a Cypher query until it returns 0 or `NULL`) and `apoc.coll.subtract` (which subtracts one collection from another). In this example, a `Temp` node is created to keep temporary data, and it is deleted at the end. The returned `result` should be a collection of objects. Each object will have a `subgraph_ids` collection that contains the native IDs of the nodes that belong in the same subgraph.

```
MATCH (n:H)-[:Rel1|Rel2]-(:X)-[:Rel1|Rel2]-(:H)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT ID(n)) AS ids
CREATE (x:Temp {ids: ids, result: []})
WITH x
CALL apoc.periodic.commit(
  "MATCH (x:Temp) " +
  "CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(x.ids[0], {relationshipFilter:'Rel1|Rel2', labelFilter:'H|X', filterStartNode:false, limit:-1}) YIELD node " +
  "WITH x, COLLECT(ID(node)) AS subgraph_ids " +
  "SET x.ids = apoc.coll.subtract(x.ids, subgraph_ids) " +
  "SET x.result = x.result + {subgraph_ids: subgraph_ids} " +
  "RETURN SIZE(x.ids);"
  ,
  NULL) YIELD updates
WITH x, x.result AS result
DELETE x
RETURN result;
```

The `MATCH` clause at the top finds `H` nodes that belong to subgraphs with at least 2 `Rel1` and/or `Rel2` relationships. The native IDs of those nodes are used to initialize the `ids` collection of the `Temp` node.

The Cypher code executed by `apoc.periodic.commit` will repeatedly:

- take the first ID from `ids`
- get the nodes in the subgraph (with `Rel|Rel2` types and `X|H` labels) that contains the node with that ID
- subtract the IDs of the subgraph nodes from `ids`
- add an object with a collection of the subgraph node IDs to the `result` collection of the `Temp` node
- return the current size of the `ids` collection (if it is 0, then `apoc.periodic.commit` will finish execution).

You can modify this query to return the actual nodes, to filter for nodes with a particular label, an so forth.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16840702)

Comment: Fleshed out the answer with a nice example.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

In general I'd suggest looking into writing a custom `Evaluator` class for your `TraversalDescription` to consume. There you can easily include/exclude/prune etc based on node or relationship types. Think of the Evaluator as a set of rules which your traversal will repeatedly refer to with each Path it finds. Here's a basic example.

For the Evaluator:

```
public class MyEvaluator implements Evaluator {
    Label someLabel; 

    @Override
    public execute(Path path) {

        if (path.length() == 0) {
            return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
        }

        if (path.lastRelationship().getEndNode().hasLabel(someLabel)) {
            return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
        }
        return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;
    }
}
```

Then plug that into a TraversalDescription:

```
public Stream<Path> myTraversal(Node startNode) {    
    GraphDatabaseService db;

    TraversalDescription td = db.getTraversalDescription().evaluator(new MyEvaluator()).depthFirst();

    Traverser tv = td.traverse(someStartNode);
    return tv.stream();
}
```

Are you putting this in a stored procedure, or embedded instance?

Comment: Thanks ramen, can you give an example of how can we start the traversal given in node type with  the `Evaluator`